# Communicating between networks using sockets

Tags: sockets, networking

I have a question about network connections among computers.
I've made some applications where messages pass through the Internet (via sockets) to make a connection between two devices. However, a strong condition is that two devices must be connected to the same network.

Can anyone give me a trick how to create a communication using sockets between two computers even if they are connected to different netwkorks?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a great tutorial on how to use sockets and general networking
>   (in java)
>  http://www.thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=25&number=38

In order to communicate between two diffrent networks over the internet, you will need to do something called **port forwarding**. What that does is that when your public IP of your network receives a packet with a spesific port number. The router knows where to send that packet to which local IP.

If you dont port forward and receive some data. The router doesent know where to send the packet. Therefore it discards it, which means others wont be able to connect to you.

You will only need to port forward the network with your server (using the example i linked). How you do that is by logging in to your router, and say that a port which the server uses gets forwarded to the IP of the PC hosting the server.

On the other network (client) you will need to change the IP address of which the client shall connect to. That IP address needs to be your **public IP** of your server's network. You can find that by connecting to the server's network and go to: http://www.whatsmyip.org/    . Keep in mind  that public IP addresses may **change over time**.

Hope this helped!
-Kad